# Matrix representation of functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Suppose $V$ is a nonzero finite-dimensional vector space over $F$. A linear functional is $f: V \rightarrow F$. Prove that there exists ordered bases $C$ for $V$, and $D$ for $F$ so that $A_{ij}$, the entries of $A$, matrix representation of $f$ in the bases $C, D$, is $0$ or $1$.

My attempt:

Suppose $C = \{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ and $D = \{f_1, ..., f_n\}$ be bases for $V$ and its dual $V^*$, where:

$$f_{i}(vj) = \delta_{ij}$$

The $1$ x $n$ matrix $A = [f]_{C, D}$ is as follows:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
[fv_1]_D ... [fv_n]_D
\end{bmatrix}$$

Notice that for some $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, $fv_j = f_iv_j = \delta_{ij}$

$f_iv_j = \delta_{ij} \implies [f_iv_j]_D = \delta_{ij}$

QED.

I'm not sure if this proof is correct as it seems a little iffy. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: "Suppose $C,D$ be bases ..." The existence of such bases is exactly what the question is asking.

Comment: Per the problem, $D$ is supposed to be a basis for $F$, not $V^*$. Nor do I see any reason at all to believe that for some $i, fv_j = f_iv_j$ The $v_j$ were just some arbitrary basis and the $f_i$ the corresponding cobasis in $V^*$. In neither one did $f$ have any influence on the picking. And since $D$ is a basis for $V^*$ and $fv_i \in F$, the notation $[fv_i]_D$ is meaningless.